# Create dictionary regrouped by keys

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe

```
City     Day        Hour   Temperature 
Paris    Monday     15       40
Paris    Monday     15       25
paris    Saturday   14       15
Chicago  Sunday     16       20
Chicago  Sunday     02       40
Chicago  Sunday     16       35
```

I want to create a dictionary that regroup mean temperature by city by day by Hour

```
dict[paris][monday][15] = 32.5
dict[paris][saturday][14] = 15
dict[Chicago][sunday][16] = 27.5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`groupby().mean()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html) and optionally build a nested `defaultdict`.

```py
# This will create a pd.Series with a MultiIndex and mean temperatures as values. 
means = df.groupby(["City", "Day", "Hour"])["Temperature"].mean()
print(means.loc[("Paris", "Monday", 15)])

# If you really need a nested dictionary like structure
d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(dict))
for (city, day, hour), mean_temp in means.iteritems():
    d[city][day][hour] = mean_temp

print(d["Paris"]["Monday"][15])
```